# replacement of Offset Limit in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, offset, sql-delete

We have `DataTemp` table which has the records in `desc` order.

```
select * from ( 
select 9,'a',3 union 
select 8,'a',2 union 
select 7,'b',3 union 
select 6,'a',1 union 
select 5,'b',2 union 
select 4,'c',3 union 
select 3,'c',2 union 
select 2,'b',1 union 
select 1,'c',1 
) door (sno,id, N_th_Reocord)
```

1. `sno` - Auto Id.
2. `id`  - code of the Doors*.
3. `N_th_Record` - for denoting the `n` the record.

At a time, only three* records per Door are need to store on this table. For example Door 'a' has new entry(means 4th record) then first of 'a' Door need to delete.

**4th record:**

```
select * from ( 
select 10,'a',4 union --- new entry 
select 9,'a',3 union 
select 8,'a',2 union 
select 7,'b',3 union 
select 6,'a',1 union -- need to delete
select 5,'b',2 union 
select 4,'c',3 union 
select 3,'c',2 union 
select 2,'b',1 union 
select 1,'c',1 
) door (sno,id, N_th_Reocord)
```

I do following query. But I need easiest way for deleting the row. Because, we are try to reduce the time consumption of over all project.

```
delete from door where sno = (
 select sno from ( 
  select 10,'a',4 union 
  select 9,'a',3 union 
  select 8,'a',2 union 
  select 7,'b',3 union 
  select 6,'a',1 union 
  select 5,'b',2 union 
  select 4,'c',3 union 
  select 3,'c',2 union 
  select 2,'b',1 union 
  select 1,'c',1 
 ) door (sno,id, N_th_Reocord) 
 where id = 'a' 
 order by sno desc -- For 'DataTemp' *order by* is no needed. 
 offset 3 rows fetch next 1 rows only 
)
```

**Note:**

1. Three rows and three Door are given for example. Actually we work with 144 rows per 12 Doors.
2. Before this delete, we check lot of Business rules.
3. Version: SQL Server 2012

Comment: *"Before this delete, we check lot of Business rules. "* and yet you exempt this from your post, despite that they are a requirement of your `DELETE`process? None of your SQL has a `DELETE` in it either; are we missing that?

Comment: @Larnu i did not get you exactly what you are try to say. But Our instruction is delete the excess record of particular door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sno DESC) rn FROM t)
DELETE FROM cte WHERE rn > 3;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4d5bc52141439a0be6315fa4c0590f12)**

Comment: You need to compare actual execution plans. Please note that your version of `OFFSET FETCH` works on single door, `ROW_NUMBER` is handling all doors at once

Comment: Now i have no time for study about execution plan. That's why I ask help in SO. This will be used in `Trigger`. So, one door is processed at a time. Will accept your answer in daytime after testing. Thanks for your support.